# don't understand typecasting in C

Tags: c, type-conversion

I've read some of the questions and didn't find what I was looking for.
Here is an example of typecasting (I saw it in some video)

```
    int s = 45;
    double d = *(double *) &s;
```

(this example is shown to demonstrate how data can be lost if you do this kind of typecasting.)
But I can't understand what is the difference between example above and this.

```
    int s = 45;
    double d = (double) &s;
```

or this

```
    int s = 45;
    double d = (double) s;
```

Comment: Well, the second results in 45.  The first might result in an access violation, since double is twice as wide as int on most systems.

Comment: @Mitch The second does not necessarily result in 45 at all.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  I misread it as (double)s.  My mistake.

Comment: Understanding the examples requires understanding of the address operator `&` and its inverse, the dereference operator `*`. Once you understand what they are doing the expressions should be clear. Then you need to read about aliasing in order to understand why you shouldn't do 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example:

```
int s = 45;
double d = (double) &s;
```

You take the address of `s` using `& operator`, and ***cast the address itself to `double`***

In the first case:

```
int s = 45;
double d = *(double *) &s;
```

You take the address of `s` using `& operator`, than you refer to this address as if it pointed a double `(double *) &s`

Now you have a pointer to a double which is located in the same address where your `int` is.

using the `*` operator you take the value in this ***double pointer***.

note that the cast occurs before the de-reference! as if it was:

```
int s = 45;
double d = *((double *) &s);
```

We can separate into lines for it to be easier to understand:

```
int s = 45;
unsigned int addressOfS = &s;
double* pointerToTheSameNumAsPointerToDouble = (double*)addressOfS;
double theValueInThatPointer = *pointerToTheSameNumAsPointerToDouble;
```

Answer (score 0):

`(double *) &s` 
Means that we are casting the memory address of `s` as a **pointer to** a double (since `s` is actually a double).

`(double) &s` 
Means that we are casting the memory address of `s` as a **double** which is not correct (the memory address of a variable should be casted as a **pointer** to that type).

For example:

```
char s = 'c';
char *s_pointer = (char *)&s;

int t = 1;
int *t_pointer = (int *)&t;
```

etc,etc